# Increment column for streaks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, gaps-and-islands

How do I get the following result highlighted in yellow?
[image]

Essentially I want a calculated field which increments by 1 when VeganOption = 1 and is zero when VeganOption = 0

I have tried using the following query but using partition continues to increment after a zero. I'm a bit stuck on this one.

```
SELECT [UniqueId]
      ,[Meal]
      ,[VDate]
      ,[VeganOption]
      , row_number() over (partition by [VeganOption] order by [UniqueId])
  FROM [Control]
  order by [UniqueId]
```

Table Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Control
    ([UniqueId] int, [Meal] varchar(10), [VDate] datetime, [VeganOption] int);

INSERT INTO Control ([UniqueId], [Meal], [VDate], [VeganOption])
VALUES
('1', 'Breakfast',' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
('2', 'Lunch',' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
('3', 'Dinner',' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
('4', 'Breakfast',' 2018-08-02 00:00:00', 1),
('5', 'Lunch',' 2018-08-02 00:00:00', 0),
('6', 'Dinner',' 2018-08-02 00:00:00', 0),
('7', 'Breakfast',' 2018-08-03 00:00:00', 1),
('8', 'Lunch',' 2018-08-03 00:00:00', 1),
('9', 'Dinner',' 2018-08-03 00:00:00', 1),
('10', 'Breakfast',' 2018-08-04 00:00:00', 0),
('11', 'Lunch',' 2018-08-04 00:00:00', 1),
('12', 'Dinner',' 2018-08-04 00:00:00', 1)
;
```

This is for SQL Server 2016+

Comment: I know the upvotes show it, but it's so nice to see a well formulated question, with sample data, expected results, an attempt, and then to top it off both a `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Larnu And not the usual trivial conversion failed from varchar to datetime for a chagne :-)

Comment: It's the "how to I split this delimited list" questions that really bug me @ZoharPeled . So many of them.... Lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create subgroups using `SUM` and then `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [UniqueId]
      ,[Meal]
      ,[VDate]
      ,[VeganOption]
      ,sum(CASE WHEN VeganOption = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
         over (order by [UniqueId]) AS grp  --switching 0 <-> 1
  FROM [Control]
)
SELECT *,CASE WHEN VeganOption =0 THEN 0
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY veganOption, grp ORDER BY [UniqueId])
        END AS VeganStreak                  -- main group and calculated subgroup
FROM cte
order by [UniqueId];
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/YDKL65668)**

Comment: I like this approach, slightly easier to understand than the other traditional approaches to gaps and islands.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant on gaps-and-islands.

I like to define streaks using the difference of row numbers.  This looks like

```
select c.*,
       (case when veganoption = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by veganoption, seqnum - seqnum_v order by uniqueid)
             else 0
        end) as veganstreak
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by veganoption order by uniqueid) as seqnum_v,
             row_number() over (order by uniqueid) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c;
```

Why this works is a bit hard to explain.  But, if you look at the results of the subquery, you'll see how the difference of row numbers defines the streaks you want to identify.  The rest is just applying `row_number()` to enumerate the meals.

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/MMVAO82146).

Comment: It produces incorrect result: http://rextester.com/YDVD78565. Last two rows (4,5) instead of (1,2)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . Thank you for putting that together.  I didn't notice that the date is not unique.  The `uniqueid` is the right column to use for the logic.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use a CTE to define your groupings, and then do a further `ROW_NUMBER()` on those, resulting in:

```
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID ASC) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VeganOption ORDER BY UniqueID ASC) AS Grp
    FROM Control)
SELECT *,
       CASE VeganOption WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY UniqueID ASC) END
FROM Grps
ORDER BY UniqueId;
```

Comment: You should zero VeganOption = 0 http://rextester.com/COTWN74238. Rows 5,6 should be (0,0) instead (1,2). Same for row 10.